# jQuery - Pass HTML with JS variable as parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a namespace called "X" and it has a `getJSON` function that fetches some file from the server. I want to reuse this namespace with varying contents. Here is the code:

```
var uid = "27D76901-B6B1-B332-918B-D9F5A7152EFC";
var X = {
    el: "",
    elMarkup: "",
    url: "",
    initialize: function(el, elMarkup, url){
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            el.find("p").remove().end();
            $.each(data.comments, function(key, value){
                el.append(elMarkup);
            })
        })
    }
};

X.el = $("#comments");
X.elMarkup = "<p>"+ value.content +" by "+ value.user +"</p>";
X.url = "http://example.com/getComments?uid=" + uid;
X.initialize(X.el, X.elMarkup, X.url);
```

I am having a problem with the `elMarkup` variable for the `$.each` loop. How can I define this variable dynamically? Thanks!

Comment: `X.elMarkup = "<p>"+ value.content +" by "+ value.user +"</p>";` will give you `undefined` for both variables as they are not defined outside the function.

Comment: @nnnnnn If I am going to define the value variables inside the loop, then I will not be able to reuse the namespace. Other json results does not contain the same array. I need the loop to accept varying value variables.

Comment: Yes, I realised just after posting the comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
X.elMarkup = function(value) {
   return "<p>"+ value.content +" by "+ value.user +"</p>";
};
```

And then in your `$.getJSON()` callback:

```
        $.each(data.comments, function(key, value){
            el.append(elMarkup(value));
        });
```

That is, instead of defining `X.elMarkup` as a string, define it as a callback function that generates the particular html structure you need. Then your generic `initialize()` function just has to call `elMarkup()` and pass the current value that needs formatting.

Note that it doesn't really make sense to set the properties as `X.el = ...` if you're just going to pass those properties as arguments to the `X.initialize()` function. It would make more sense to just pass the required values directly and have `X.initialize()` save the values as properties if needed. Or set the properties and call `X.initialize()` with no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
$.each(data.comments, function(key, value){
    el.append(elMarkup);
})
```

to

```
$.each(data.comments, function(key, value){
    el.append($('<p />', {"html": value.content + " by " + value.user}));
})
```

because of the reason I mentioned in comment.